# source code to integrate video support for H.263,H.264,MPEG4 in Video conferencing

Tags: ios4

I want to implement video conferencing functionaality in iPhone SDK.....

For this VMobile Mobile Video Conference Call Specification:
--- for Video support we need :

1. H.263
2. H.264
3. MPEG4

Can u suggest any source code to implement the above video compressing technologies in our application

Answer (score 1):

Absolute best projects to look at.

The first one (VLC) has actually been ported to iPad (so I've heard).

http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

This project implements libavcodec, which has native decode support for H264, and supports H264 *encode* through support of the project in the *above* link.

http://ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg is a widely used library - see discussion on [codza](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone) for iPhone porting details.
Do be aware that, depending on compile options, FFmpeg license is GPL or LGPL - [see this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064075/what-is-ffmpeg) about FFmpeg distribution.